# How to check whether my object has a key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am executing three different cases for my login method, on successful login i receive the below `auth` token

```
{"auth":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6IkRpZGllci5EZXNjaGFtcHNAbm93aGVyZS5jb20iLCJoYXNoIjoiMFIzM3lnckhJNTNjNDg1NDA4YzliZWUzZDEyM2UwZTQwY2I3OTc3YWEiLCJuYW1lIjoiRGlkaWVyIiwidXNlcmlkIjoyLCJhY2NvdW50aWQiOjB9.884v-blMRHE-VgYOvuJIOwZHNhuaKuhprYO9xU6IYtE"}
```

How do i check whether my `user object has the auth key` or not in `rspec` to pass the test.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  context "when signing in" do

    it "should not login with invalid code" do       
      user = User.login(email: email, password: password, confirmpassword: password, code: 10000);
    end

    it "should not login with no code" do 
      user = User.login(email: email, password: password, confirmpassword: password, code: "");
    end

    it "should login with valid code" do 
      user = User.login(email: email, password: password, confirmpassword: password, code: 0);
    end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
expect(user.auth).not_to be_nil
```

vs

```
expect(user.auth).to be_nil
```

Comment: I can execute three it statements inside a context right?

Comment: You can execute as many `it`s within context as you need, this is what context is for.

Comment: I am just worried, if the response does not have a auth key itself... in that case user.auth.to be_nil might fail

Comment: Why wouldn't it have this key? I have too little information about your models to tell you more, but if you are using external APIs, you should always stub them in your tests.

Comment: Then naturally your test has to fail. Isn't that what you are testing here?

Comment: Yup that would fail, would that be more helpful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59092/discussion-between-broisatse-and-undertaker).

Comment: Can you just check this thread and let me know whether its right what i am doing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273062/rspec-checking-for-json-response

Answer (score 1):

I think that something like

```
expect(user).to have_key(:auth)
```

and

```
expect(user).to_not have_key(:auth)
```

can do the job.

check the [docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers) for more matchers.

Comment: `have_key` is reserved for hashes. Unfortunately, even though ActiveRecord defines `[]` method, ti is not a hash and does not respond to `has_key` method, hence the above won't work.